# Sublime Text Editor: Boxes Appear instead of Spaces

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

[image]

I might have pressed something on my keyboard by accident. The spaces on my code turned into boxes and it's annoying. How do I remove it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have opened the Find panel and searched for a space. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close the find panel and the boxes will disappear. Alternatively turn off "highlight matches" in the find panel.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't for the life of me figure out what I had done.